# Mod rewrite everything except specific subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect everything except the subfolders `admin` and `api` to `admin`, so:

```
/           - redirects to /admin
/some-url   - redirects to /admin
/admin      - doesn't redirect
/admin/1    - doesn't redirect
/api        - doesn't redirect
/api/v1/etc - doesn't redirect
```

but what I've got so far doesn't redirect correctly. Here's my mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin|api)
  RewriteRule ^ /admin [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` as `REQUEST_URI` changes its value due to last rule and then in next iteration of `mod_rewrite` rewrite condition in first rule returns true.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(admin|api) [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ /admin [R,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```